# How to get the Row values into columns from a table(to use in Pivot)-SQl Developer

Tags: sql, pivot

My Data looks like

```
Company  Product  Available
ABC      Rice     Yes
XYZ      Wheat    Yes
ABC      Wheat    No
ABC      Sugar    Yes
XYZ      Sugar    No
PQR      Salt     Yes
```

I need to display the data (After Pivot) like this:

```
     Wheat  Rice  Sugar Salt
ABC  No     Yes   Yes   -
XYZ  Yes    -     No    -
PQR  -      -     -     Yes
```

Here I have a problem because there are 4 Products in sample data but I am not sure about number of products in original data so I need to write an SQL query for a variable number of products.

Please help me in writing a Pivot query (my column values are dynamic)

Comment: You can't write just a pivot query with dynamic number of columns... you have to use dynamic SQL, IMHO I think using joins is easier when writing dynamic SQL

Comment: Also, there is no vanilla SQL solution to this -- you are going to have to tell us the platform (MSSQL, Oracle, DB2, mySQL etc)